# Navigating to beginning/end of words/lines in the python console

Tags: macos, python

I am running the python console in my terminal on OSX and I would like to know if there are any keyboard shortcuts for navigating to the next/previous word or to the beginning or end of the line.

In my text editor for example I can use CMD + RIGHT ARROW to get to the end of a line, but this doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Python that comes with OS X, it was not built with Readline support at least in 10.8. You can still use basic Emacs-style keybindings:

- control-A: go to beginning of line
- control-E: go to end of line
- option-B: go word backward
- option-F: go word forward
- control-K: delete to end of line
- control-U: clear line
- option-D: delete word forward
- option-delete: delete word backward

If you installed Python with Homebrew, it was probably configured with Readline support, so you can use the [same keybindings as in Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Interaction).